# how to include 'all' search option in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, stored-procedures

I'm trying to put an `ALL` search function for my aspx page. The problem is that I have no idea how to do it properly. This is as far as I can go, here's the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dtTransactionCategory = clsTransactionCategory.GetTransactionCategory(Helper.LogID, Helper.OrgID, Helper.SiteID, 0, string.Empty);
        ddlTransactionCategoryDesc.DataSource = dtTransactionCategory;
        ddlTransactionCategoryDesc.DataTextField = "TransactionCategoryDesc";
        ddlTransactionCategoryDesc.DataValueField = "TransactionCategoryID";
        ddlTransactionCategoryDesc.DataBind();
        ddlTransactionCategoryDesc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All"));

        ddlTransactionCategoryInput.DataSource = dtTransactionCategory;
        ddlTransactionCategoryInput.DataTextField = "TransactionCategoryDesc";
        ddlTransactionCategoryInput.DataValueField = "TransactionCategoryID";
        ddlTransactionCategoryInput.DataBind();

        logID = CommonFunctions.StringToInt(Session[Constants.SessionLogID].ToString());
        orgID = 1;
        siteID = 1;
        ddlTransactionCategoryDesc.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(ddlTransactionCategoryDesc);
        txtTransactionDesc.Text = string.Empty;
        BindData();
    }
}
```

and the stored procedure, should it needed:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spMSTransaction_Get] 
@OrgID INT,
@SiteID INT,
@TransactionCategoryID INT,
@TransactionCategoryDesc varchar (300),
@TransactionDesc varchar(300)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT mst.[OrgID], 
            mst.[SiteID], 
            mst.[TransactionID],
            mst.[TransactionCategoryID], 
            mstc.[TransactionCategoryDesc],
            mst.[TransactionDesc], 
            mst.[IsActive], 
            [master].dbo.fnConvertUTCToLocalTimeZone (mst.[CreatedDate]) as [CreatedDate],
            mst.[CreatedBy], 
            [master].dbo.fnConvertUTCToLocalTimeZone (mst.[ModifiedDate]) as [ModifiedDate],  
            mst.[ModifiedBy] 
    FROM [dbo].[MSTransaction] AS mst
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[MSTransactionCategory] AS mstc
    ON mst.OrgID = mstc.OrgID  AND mst.SiteID = mstc.SiteID AND mst.TransactionCategoryID = mstc.TransactionCategoryID
    WHERE (mst.[OrgID] = @OrgID OR @OrgID = 0) 
            AND (mst.[SiteID] = @SiteID OR @SiteID = 0) 
            AND (mst.[TransactionCategoryID] = @TransactionCategoryID OR @TransactionCategoryID = 0)
            AND (mst.[TransactionDesc] LIKE '%' + @TransactionDesc + '%')
            AND (mst.[isActive] = 1)
```

I already put `ddlTransactionCategoryDesc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All"));` but it returned an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Any idea what I need to fix and what I should do to make the `ALL` search function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Stored Procedure, `@TransactionCategoryID` is an `INT`. Adding the `ALL` list will require you use the following instead:

```
ddlTransactionCategoryDesc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0"));
```

This will make the value of `ALL` to be an `INT`. What you currently have - `ListItem("All")` automatically changes the type of the Value to a string. Check your dropdown after execution, it will show the value as `All` but that cannot be passed into the `INT` that the Stored Proc requires.

Comment: i tried your solution and it throws an error: **'cannot convert from 'int' to 'string''** any idea?

Comment: Use ListItem("All","0"). I mistakenly forgot to make the value into a string, which is a requirement for ListItem. I will edit the answer too.